# Cannot pass a string array from external data file postman automation scripts

Tags: arrays, string, automation, postman

I'm trying to pass a string array in postman- post request

postman request- body

```
{
"fruits":[{{fruits}}],

 }
```

postman- test

```
var fruits=["mango","apple","orange"]
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
fruits.push(jsonData.fruits.toString());
}

pm.globals.set("fruits", fruits);
```

Then set fruits as global variables
[image: gloabal variables]

Then run the API through the collection runner with the external data file. Then check the response body and I got this
[image: can't pass the array as string]

got a 404 error

If anyone can let me know how to pass a array as a string in postman. When we pass a string array it will defined as a ascii value. So this issue has happened. So please guide me through this.

Comment: What is the expected json?

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 {"fruits":["mango","apple","orange"]} expected result should be inside the double quotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to save an array as a variable, remember to `stringify` this.

```
let fruits=["mango","apple","orange"]
pm.globals.set("fruits", JSON.stringify(fruits));
```

Second, you don't need to add `[ ]` in request body, just put the variable

```
{
    "fruits": {{fruits}}
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "fruits": ["mango","apple","orange"]
}
```

Comment: This answer is worked for me . thanks :)